# iOS app shows wrong if a post is a question or an answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app

Today I was navigating my profile in the iOS app and noticed a minor bug. When you see the list of posts in a profile you can see that it states "Q" or "A" to know if it is a question or an answer:

[image: List of posts]

Then if you click "all X posts" you see a detailed list and there, the posts that are questions are listed as answers, and the answers don't show anything, as you can see here:

[image: Detailed list of posts]

For example, the "URL pattern in Spark" is a question and is listed as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No bug here. This is listed as question, by being prefixed by a "Q" just like in the other list:

> [image]

Not sure how you missed that, maybe because of the answer icon which means "this question got X answers", in this case one answer.

Comment: How could I miss that? You are totally right..